# How can send dropdownlist value from Controller to another controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to  send  dropdownlist selected value from Controller to another controller

and recuperate that value   (i know how to send it )  but i dont know how to  recuperat it

controller 1:

```
public class PosteController : Controller
{

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(CandidateModel Id)
    {

       return RedirectToAction ("Inscription","Candidate",Id);

    }



public class CandidateController : Controller
{

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Inscription()
    {

       ...........

    }
```

Comment: You can't "Redirect" to an action that is a POST. You either need to turn that action into an `HttpGet` or POST to the correct action in the first place.

Comment: the problem that  Inscription is also a HttpPOst  methode

Comment: here in your question "Id" is dropdown value or CandidateModel object???

Comment: just clarify your question first...

Comment: it's a dropdown value (but it's  an attribute in a model )

Comment: in your question you are making CandidateModel Id...Id as object then how it is dropdown selected value????

Comment: @saidmohamed11....problem solved..????

Comment: actually yes   i  forgot to mad it solved   ( i  have  a  lot of other problems  :p)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Method 1:

**Using Object Route :**

```
public class PosteController : Controller
{     
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(CandidateModel Id)
    {
       return RedirectToAction ("Inscription","Candidate",new{ dropdownval=Id.val,Id });  
    }

public class CandidateController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Inscription(int? dropdownval)
    {
       ...........
    }
```

### Method 2:

**Using TempData:**

```
public class PosteController : Controller
{     
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(CandidateModel Id)
    {
       TempData["Id"]=Id.val;
       return RedirectToAction ("Inscription","Candidate"); 
    }

public class CandidateController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Inscription()
    {
      var id=TempData["Id"];
       ...........
    }
```

In above examples `Id.val` is the selected dropdown value.

Comment: RedirectToAction will perform a GET, not a post.

Comment: If you change the action to use GET there's no reason to use `TempData`

Comment: i m using tempdata to pass data from one controller to another..@Shoe

Comment: @Shoe..i m giving two answers for the question

Answer (score 1):

You can use [TempData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd394711(v=vs.90).aspx) for this.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(CandidateModel Id)
{
   TempData["var"] = id;
   return RedirectToAction ("Inscription","Candidate",Id);

}

public ActionResult Inscription()
{

   var id = TempData["id"] as CandidateModel;

}
```

Comment: RedirectToAction will perform a GET, not a post.

Comment: user wants to send dropdown value and in your answer just check this line... var id = TempData["id"] as CandidateModel;

Comment: @Exception He can add any value to the TempData. I just created an example of the use of TempData.

Comment: There's no point in `TempData` here. You could just specify `id` as a route value for the Inscription action.

Comment: @Shoe You are right, using the parameter way is actually better because you don't use the Session-object.